# Matching a regexp in TCL PERL

Tags: regex, tcl

I am having follwing pattern

```
    Pattern[1]: 
    Key : "key1" 
    Value : 100
    Pattern[2]: 
    Key : "key2" 
    Value : 20
    Pattern[3]: 
    Key : "key3" 
    Value : 30
    Pattern[4]: 
    Key : "key4" 
    Value : 220
```

I want to segregate each `Pattern` block . I am using TCL . Regexp that I am using is not resolving the purpose

```
set updateList [regexp -all -inline {Pattern\[\d+\].*?Value.*?\n} $list]
```

Which Regexp to use to segregate each pattern

I need output as

```
    Pattern[1]: 
    Key : "key1" 
    Value : 100


    Pattern[2]: 
    Key : "key2" 
    Value : 20


    Pattern[3]: 
    Key : "key3" 
    Value : 30


    Pattern[4]: 
    Key : "key4" 
    Value : 220
```

Comment: Perhaps, `Pattern\[\d+\]:\s*Key.*\s*Value.*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : It is not working

Comment: `set updateList [regexp -all -inline {Pattern\[[0-9]+\]:\s*Key[^\n]*\s*Value[^\n]*} $str]` is. A dot is matching a newline in Tcl, that is why the one above did not work.

Comment: See Wiktor's answer: all you need to do is change `\d+` to `\d+?`

Comment: @glennjackman: Almost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern `Pattern\[\d+\].*?Value.*?\n` contains mixed quantifiers: both greedy and lazy. Tcl does not handle mixed quantifier type as you would expect it in, say, PCRE (PHP, Perl), .NET, etc., it defaults to the first found one, as the subsequent quantifiers inherit the preceding quantifier type. So, the `+` after `\d` is greedy, thus, all others (in `.*?`) are also greedy - even if you declared them to be lazy. Also, the `.` matches a newline in Tcl regex, too, so, your pattern works like [this](https://regex101.com/r/nX2jZ0/1).

So, based on your regex, you can **make the `\d+` lazy with `\d+?` and replace `\n` at the end with `(?:\n|$)` to match both the newline and the end of string**:

```
set RE {Pattern\[\d+?\].*?Value.*?(?:\n|$)}
set updateList [regexp -all -inline $RE $str]
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/VSZBx6)

**Alternative 1**

Also, you can use a more verbose regex if your input string always has the same structure with all elements - `Pattern`, `Key`, `Value` -  present:

```
set updateList [regexp -all -inline {Pattern\[\d+\]:\s*Key[^\n]*\s*Value[^\n]*} $str]
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/kAnNpA), and here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zL4xA2/3).

Since a `.` can match a newline, we need to use a `[^\n]` negated character class matching any character but a line feed.

**Alternative 2**

You can use an unrolled lazy subpattern matching `Pattern[n]:` and then any character that is not a starting point for a `Pattern[n]:` sequence:

```
set RE {Pattern\[\d+\]:[^P]*(?:P(?!attern\[\d+\]).)*}
set updateList [regexp -all -inline $RE $str]
```

See [another IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/mvO45u) and a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/zL4xA2/4)

Comment: Here is [another, shorter, demo](https://ideone.com/O1INgr) proving my point about the lazy-to-greedy "conversion" in your regex: `\d+[a-zA-Z]+?\d+?` should match `56gddd6` in `56gddd666`, but it matches the whole string, because the last `\d+?` is actually acting as a greedy subpattern (which was inherited from the `[a-zA-Z]+?` that was acting as a greedy subpattern since it inherited that behavior from the first `\d+` one).

Comment: Good explanation about the pattern's greediness choice. Given that, changing `\d+` to `\d+?` will work for the OP, since all the other quantifier's are non-greedy too.

Comment: @glennjackman: I also thought about that, but there is one more caveat: the last item is not followed with a newline. An alternation group is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Pattern\[\d+\](.|\n)*?Value.*?\n
```

The dot *.* character matches any characters but line break, so you need to add it in. Be aware that your line may end with a carriage character so you might need to add *\r* in.

Answer (score 1):

You want to capture blocks of lines and output them with blank lines in between. Your example data displays patterns on different levels that can be used to recognize which lines belong to which block.

The simplest pattern is this: every three lines in the input make up a block. This pattern suggests processing like this:

```
set lines [split [string trim $list \n] \n]
foreach {a b c} $lines {puts $a\n$b\n$c\n\n}
```

There is nothing in your example data that suggests that this wouldn't work. Still, there may be some complications that aren't reflected in your example data.

If there are stray blank lines in the input, you might need to get rid of them first:

```
set lines [lmap line $lines {if {[string is space $line]} continue else {set line}}]
```

If some blocks contain less or more lines than in your example, another simple pattern is that every block starts with a line that has optional(?) whitespace and the word `Pattern`. Those lines (except the first) should be preceded by a block-delimiter in the output:

```
set lines [split [string trim $list \n] \n]
puts [lindex $lines 0]
foreach line [lrange $lines 1 end] {
    if {[regexp {\s*Pattern} $line]} {
        puts \n$line
    } else {
        puts $line
    }
}
puts \n
```

If the lines don't actually begin with whitespace, you could use `string match Pattern* $line` instead of the regular expression.

Documentation: [continue](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/continue.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [lmap](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570) replacement, [lrange](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lrange.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: I like it. You're assuming (reasonably) there are no newlines in the key value, or any "accidental" blank lines.

Comment: Adding an explanation of how this code answers the question will improve your answer for future visitors (this answer was flagged as low-quality).

Answer (score 1):

```
% set list {    Pattern[1]: 
    Key : "key1" 
    Value : 100
    Pattern[2]: 
    Key : "key2" 
    Value : 20
    Pattern[3]: 
    Key : "key3" 
    Value : 30
    Pattern[4]: 
    Key : "key4" 
    Value : 220
}
% regexp -all -inline {Pattern\[\d+\].*?Value.*?\n} $list
{Pattern[1]: 
    Key : "key1" 
    Value : 100
    Pattern[2]: 
    Key : "key2" 
    Value : 20
    Pattern[3]: 
    Key : "key3" 
    Value : 30
    Pattern[4]: 
    Key : "key4" 
    Value : 220
}
% regexp -all -inline {Pattern\[\d+?\].*?Value.*?\n} $list   ;# only changing `\d+` to `\d+?`
{Pattern[1]: 
    Key : "key1" 
    Value : 100
} {Pattern[2]: 
    Key : "key2" 
    Value : 20
} {Pattern[3]: 
    Key : "key3" 
    Value : 30
} {Pattern[4]: 
    Key : "key4" 
    Value : 220
}
```

If $list does *not* end with a newline, you won't get the "pattern[4]" element returned. In that case, change

```
% regexp -all -inline {Pattern\[\d+?\].*?Value.*?\n} $list
```

to

```
% regexp -all -inline {Pattern\[\d+?\].*?Value.*?(?:\n|$)} $list
```